# Post-save method to handle calculations in django admin forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models: Estimate and Product. Product's form is included as TabularInline inside Estimate's admin form. Each instance of Estimate creates at least one instance of Product. What I'm trying to do is calculate a total of Product's subtotals and have it show up in the estimate model after saving the instance for the first time. Code could probably explain what I'm trying to do better.

I tried overriding Estimate's Save method and I tried post-save signals (it's commented out). Everything works the way I want it to, except I have to save the model instance twice to trigger the calculate function. My question is, is there a way to cut this process short? Have it entirely done with the first save?

models.py

```
class Estimate(models.Model):
    #other irrelevant fields
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        subtotals = Product.objects.filter(estimate_id=self.id).aggregate(pr_total=Sum('subtotal'))['pr_total'] or 0
        self.total = subtotals
        if self.tax:
            self.total = subtotals + ((subtotals * self.tax) / 100)
        super(Estimate, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    


   


# @receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Estimate)
# def calculate_total(sender, instance, **kwargs):
#     subtotals = Product.objects.filter(estimate_id=instance.id).aggregate(pr_total=Sum('subtotal'))['pr_total'] or 0
#     instance.total = subtotals
#     if instance.tax:
#         instance.total = subtotals + ((subtotals * instance.tax) / 100)
        
#     signals.post_save.disconnect(calculate_total, sender=Estimate)
#     instance.save()
#     signals.post_save.connect(calculate_total, sender=Estimate)



class Product(models.Model):

    
    estimate = models.ForeignKey(Estimate,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="product2"
                                )
    
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], blank=True, null=True)
    
  
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.price:
            self.subtotal = self.price * self.quantity
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and admin.py

```
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product
    readonly_fields = ["subtotal"]


class EstimateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ["total"]
    inlines = [
        ProductInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Django's Admin (Estimate page), your `Estimate` instance will be saved before `Product`'s instances.

This should work (i have also added deletion).

```py
class Estimate(models.Model):

    # fields skipped for lisibility

    def set_total(self, commit=False):
        # use of related manager `products`
        self.total = self.products.aggregate(pr_total=Sum('subtotal')).get('pr_total', 0)
        if self.tax:
            self.total *= (1 + (self.tax / 100))
        if commit:
            super(Estimate, self).save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Estimate, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Product(models.Model):

    # fields skipped for lisibility

    estimate = models.ForeignKey(Estimate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.price:
            self.subtotal = self.price * self.quantity
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.estimate.set_total(commit=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        self.estimate.set_total(commit=True)
```

Comment: This was super helpful! Worked perfectly! Thank you so so much.